# Is there any way to simplify union query while using multiple tables, with reference to main table ( Performance Optimization )

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I wonder is there any way to improve query, speed up / simplify while using multiple tables `UNION` clause with reference to only one main table.

following is the scenario, here table `reference` is my main table and `geo_loc1`,`geo_loc2`,`geo_loc2` are other tables, which will be joined based on `key1` and `key2`, these two keys exists in all table.

```
SELECT 
    reference.*,
    geo_loc1.bathy,
    geo_loc1.gravity,
    geo_loc1.magnet,
    'data1' as type
FROM 
    reference,geo_loc1 
WHERE
    reference.latitude between -30 and -10 AND 
    reference.longitude between 10 and 50 AND 
    DATE( reference.st_date ) BETWEEN '2000-07-05' AND '2011-11-10'  AND
    reference.key1 = geo_loc1.key1 AND
    reference.key2 = geo_loc1.key2
UNION
SELECT 
    reference.*,
    geo_loc2.bathy,
    Null as gravity,
    geo_loc2.magnet,
    'data2' as type
FROM 
    reference,geo_loc2 
WHERE
    reference.latitude between -30 and -10 AND 
    reference.longitude between 10 and 50 AND 
    DATE( reference.st_date ) BETWEEN '2000-07-05' AND '2011-11-10'  AND
    reference.key1 = geo_loc2.key1 AND
    reference.key2 = geo_loc2.key2
UNION
SELECT 
    reference.*,
    Null as bathy,
    Null as gravity,
    geo_loc3.magnet,
    'data3' as type
FROM 
    reference,geo_loc3 
WHERE
    reference.latitude between -30 and -10 AND 
    reference.longitude between 10 and 50 AND 
    DATE( reference.st_date ) BETWEEN '2000-07-05' AND '2011-11-10'  AND
    reference.key1 = geo_loc3.key1 AND
    reference.key2 = geo_loc3.key2
```

Whether this query can be simplified or improved ?

Comment: Yes, by using `UNION ALL` if you don't need to remove duplicates.

Comment: How ? can you please explain ?

Comment: Replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`

Comment: Also consider using a proper `INNER JOIN` rather than adding join conditions as `WHERE` clauses. It's much more readable using the proper syntax and less error prone.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to reduce query length too ? I mean its so long by char count, if its possible to get result  same as what this query does, please let me know

Comment: Long queries aren't necessarily slower than shorter queries.  For instance, you will get slightly faster performance if you replace the `reference.*` with a list of all the columns in `reference`.

Comment: Ok, I will replace `reference.*` with `reference.col1`,`reference.col2`...`reference.n`, not an issue since I have less than 15 columns in reference

Comment: @BenThurley Could you please elaborate inner join as an answer with syntax,  which you stated in above comment

Comment: Is it mysql or something else?

Comment: @AnilKumar Yes `mysql/Mariadb`

Comment: Why are you not using reference.key1 = geo_loc1.key1 AND
    reference.key2 = geo_loc1.key2 in join with geo_loc(s) table, I see this part as a static filter to all UNIONs:    reference.latitude between -30 and -10 AND 
    reference.longitude between 10 and 50 AND 
    DATE( reference.st_date ) BETWEEN '2000-07-05' AND '2011-11-10' ?

Comment: Why you need union here, not four left joins (with geo_locs) will do the same, may you please explain?

Comment: I really didn't get you Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance I can see two things you might change.

1) Change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`. `UNION` will check the results for duplicates which adds overhead you don't need.

2) Consider changing `DATE( reference.st_date ) BETWEEN '2000-07-05' AND '2011-11-10'` to not use the date function.

If reference.st_date were a proper date column and you didn't need to do the type conversion then the DB could use an index based on date to do a quick lookup. By doing the type conversion the DB will now have to do a scan to do the conversion for each row.

You say the index is on `key1,key2,st_date,latitude,longitude`. By using the date function you're probably only using the first two columns of that index. I would either change st_date to a date or change the values you're comparing it to so the conversion isn't required.

Also consider using a proper `INNER JOIN` rather than adding join conditions as `WHERE` clauses. It's much more readable using the proper syntax and less error prone.

Example using `UNION ALL` and `INNER JOIN` should look something like this. Note this is untested obviously but you should get the idea.
**Edit** Removed use of date() function which should speed it up further

```
SELECT 
    reference.*,
    geo_loc1.bathy,
    geo_loc1.gravity,
    geo_loc1.magnet,
    'data1' as type
FROM 
    reference
INNER JOIN geo_loc1 ON
    reference.key1 = geo_loc1.key1 AND
    reference.key2 = geo_loc1.key2
WHERE
    reference.latitude between -30 and -10 AND 
    reference.longitude between 10 and 50 AND 
    reference.st_date BETWEEN '2000-07-05 00:00:00' AND '2011-11-10 23:59:59'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    reference.*,
    geo_loc2.bathy,
    Null as gravity,
    geo_loc2.magnet,
    'data2' as type
FROM 
    reference
INNER JOIN geo_loc2 ON
    reference.key1 = geo_loc2.key1 AND
    reference.key2 = geo_loc2.key2
WHERE
    reference.latitude between -30 and -10 AND 
    reference.longitude between 10 and 50 AND 
    reference.st_date BETWEEN '2000-07-05 00:00:00' AND '2011-11-10 23:59:59'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    reference.*,
    Null as bathy,
    Null as gravity,
    geo_loc3.magnet,
    'data3' as type
FROM 
    reference
INNER JOIN geo_loc3 ON
    reference.key1 = geo_loc3.key1 AND
    reference.key2 = geo_loc3.key2
WHERE
    reference.latitude between -30 and -10 AND 
    reference.longitude between 10 and 50 AND 
    reference.st_date BETWEEN '2000-07-05 00:00:00' AND '2011-11-10 23:59:59'
```

Comment: `st_date` column contains time also, so I am using date function, example value look like this: `1995-08-10 09:44:00`, could you please show me an example of inner join for current context

Comment: `INNER JOIN`  took 2msec more than `WHERE`  clause

Comment: I presume using that example that you want to include records for all times on `1995-08-10` and not just times after `09:44:00`? With DB2 you can create a "derived index" which would allow you to build an index on just the date part. MySQL doesn't support this AFAIK so you either have to separate the date value into a new column or accept the performance hit.

Comment: I didn't say `INNER JOIN` would be necessarily faster. How scientific was your test? Personally I would prefer a safer and easier to read query over a 2ms performance gain.

Comment: I use php to execute query here is sample `$start = microtime(true);

     $result = $conn->query($sql);

 $end = microtime(true);  echo "\nThis query took " . ($end - $start) . " milliseconds.\n";` whether this is correct method ?

Comment: I've just changed the example query so it doesn't use the date function on reference.st_date. This should be significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely use UNION ALL instead of UNION, since your queries cannot contain any duplicate rows.

But you will mainly get performance from good indexes, rather than from different ways of writing the query.

Comment: There is no duplicate rows, and I already have indexes , `key1,key2` for all other tables and `key1,key2,st_date,latitude,longitude` for reference table

Comment: The point is if you use `UNION` the DB will have to check every row in the resultset for duplicates. If you use `UNION ALL` you're telling it to skip this check. Hence better performance.

Comment: Ok thank you @BenThurley, it really reduces time, from 85msec to 17msec now !